# OneDrive is reporting being full from only 1GB of files, recycling bin is empty

Tags: onedrive, online-storage

Of the 5GB space on OneDrive you get for free I've put only ~1GB of files on, double checked each folder, even in OneDrive settings on my PC it says the sizes of the folders are that big (when summed manually by myself). Despite this, it insists on saying my onedrive is 4.9GB full, I've double checked the recycling bin is empty.

I've also checked the largest files and nothing seems out of the ordinary.

I've also gone online and checked each folder's details, which includes size, and indeed the numbers add up to about 1GB and appears to be working recursively as one would expect.

Anyone know what is wrong? Does the folder size checker not do so recursively (seems like it does)?

Comment: try checking [this](http://kb.mcgill.ca/?portalid=2&articleid=5974#tab:homeTab:crumb:8:artId:5974:src:article)

Comment: @user0 Thanks but I only have the free version, there doesn't appear to be that option with the free version.